# Java - Assign a number and a word to a string of inputted characters

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I am trying to make a program that will take a string, such as 'asdfg', and print words and a total number that are associated with these letters.

So 'a' would be 'apple' and its assigned number is 10, 's' would be spinach, and its assigned number is 5, 'd' would be 'dog' and its assigned number would be 15, 'f' would be 'frog' and its assigned number would be 20 and 'g' would be 'goat' and its assigned number would be 25. The output would look something like 'apple spinach dog frog goat 75'.

The code I have so far is

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;


public class PizzaTwo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the details of your order");
        String myList = scan.nextLine();


        for (int i = 0; i < myList.length(); i++) {
            int letNum = 0;
            switch (myList.charAt(i)) {
                case 'a':
                    System.out.println("apple" + letNum);
                    letNum += 10;
                    break;
                case 's':
                    System.out.println("spinach" + letNum);
                    letNum += 5;
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    System.out.println("dog" + letNum);
                    letNum += 15;
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    System.out.println("frog" + letNum);
                    letNum += 20;
                    break;
                case 'g':
                    System.out.println("goat", letNum);
                    letNum += 25;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Nothing..");
                    break;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you did not actually ask a question.

Comment: I am sorry for my ambiguity, my question is: how do I assign the number along with the word to my string of characters?

Comment: Your question is still about as clear as mud.  Is there a problem with the code you posted?  If so, what is it?  If not, why is it there?  You need to help us to help you!  See: [How to ask a good question when I'm not sure what I'm looking for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262527/how-to-ask-a-good-question-when-im-not-sure-what-im-looking-for)

Comment: Again, sorry it is very late and I am incredibly tired. The code I gave gives the correct word for each letter, ie 'a' gives 'apple' 's' gives 'spinach' etc, however I am struggling to tell it to add each of the numbers and print them, so my question would be how do I add the numbers assigned to each letter, and print them at the end of the code.

Comment: It looks to me like you're adding the numbers just fine.  I don't understand what your problem is.  My advice: nobody does their best coding when tired.  Go to bed and come back to it in the morning.

Comment: It may add the numbers fine, but it won't display them at the end of the code as it should.

Comment: However, you may be correct, off to bed I go. Thank you for at least trying to help my tired self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd like to suggest you use better names for variables.

You were resetting the "letNum" in each loop, then I've moved it out of the loop.

I recommend read about [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).
String objects are immutable, so instead to create more variables to concatenate "flavors", I used StringBuilder that are mutable.

> Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created
>
> The principal operations on a StringBuilder are the append and insert methods, which are overloaded so as to accept data of any type

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PizzaTwo {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the details of your order");
        String flavors = scan.nextLine();

        int price = 0;
        StringBuilder order = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < flavors.length(); i++) {
            switch (flavors.charAt(i)) {
            case 'a':
                order.append("apple ");
                price += 10;
                break;
            case 's':
                order.append("spinach ");
                price += 5;
                break;
            case 'd':
                order.append("dog ");
                price += 15;
                break;
            case 'f':
                order.append("frog ");
                price += 20;
                break;
            case 'g':
                order.append("goat ");
                price += 25;
                break;
            default:
                order.append("No flavor added ");
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(order.append(price));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the numbers to only appear after all the words have been printed, from your description "apple spinach dog frog goat 75", but your code looks like it's trying to append the number to the end of each word.
Assuming you want the output to be like your sample output, don't try to print the numbers after each word, instead after all the words have been printed print the variable you've been using to accumulate each letters value, 'letNum' in your code.
Also, don't reset 'letNum' each time you deal with a new letter.

Comment: That is exactly what I want. How would I go about doing that? Thanks for the response too.

Answer (score 0):

Take 2 separate variables, 1 string and another number. Each time concatenate with existing string, means something like    String s="";    int n=0;    s+="Apple";    n+=10;    s+="frog";
....
Now when loop is done print string then the number.